# Python String Replace Behaving Weirdly

Tags: python

I am trying to get users who are mentioned in an article. That is, words starting with `@` symbol and then wrap `<` and `>` around them.

**WHAT I TRIED:**

```
def getUsers(content):
    users = []
    l = content.split(' ')
    for user in l:
        if user.startswith('@'):
            users.append(user)
    return users

old_string = "Getting and replacing mentions of users. @me @mentee @you @your @us @usa @wo @world @word @wonderland"

users = getUsers(old_string)

new_array = old_string.split(' ')

for mention in new_array:
    for user in users:
        if mention == user and len(mention) == len(user):
            old_string = old_string.replace(mention, '<' + user + '>')

print old_string
print users
```

The code is behaving funny. It wraps words starting with the same alphabets and even truncate subsequent as shown in the print below:

**RESULT:**

```
Getting and replacing mentions of users. <@me> <@me>ntee <@you> <@you>r <@us> <@us>a <@wo> <@wo>rld <@wo>rd <@wo>nderland
['@me', '@mentee', '@you', '@your', '@us', '@usa', '@wo', '@world', '@word', '@wonderland']
```

**EXPECTED RESULT:**

```
Getting and replacing mentions of users. <@me> <@mentee> <@you> <@your> <@us> <@usa> <@wo> <@world> <@word> <@wonderland>
['@me', '@mentee', '@you', '@your', '@us', '@usa', '@wo', '@world', '@word', '@wonderland']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Why is this happening and how can do this the right way?

Comment: What is `a` in your code?

Comment: Since you replace `@you` first, this also changes `@your` in your string as it matches your search for `@you`

Comment: @thefourtheye: editted. a = `mention`.

Comment: Since you test `if mention == user`, that double for loop is not necessary. Just loop over all the users.

Comment: @tobias_k: This is confusing me. How do I go about this?

Comment: @Yax You seem to have a misconception here. When you replace a "mention" in the string, you are not replacing that particular substring, in this exact position, but each occurrence of that string. Thus, all the "mentions" that are equal to one "user" are indistinguishable and you just have to replace them once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why this happens: When you split the string, you put a lot of checks in to make sure you are looking at the right user e.g. you have `@me` and `@mentee` - so for user `me`, it will match the first, and not the second.

However, when you do replace, you are doing replace on the *whole string* - so when you say to replace e.g. `@me` with `<@me>`, it doesn't know anything about your careful split - it's just going to look for `@me` in the string and replace it. So `@mentee` ALSO contains `@me`, and will get replaced.

Two (well, three) choices: One is to add the spaced around it, to gate it (like @parchment wrote).

Second is to use your split: Instead of replacing the original string, replace the local piece. The simplest way to do this is with enumerate:

```
new_array = old_string.split(' ')

for index, mention in enumerate(new_array):
    for user in users:
        if mention == user and len(mention) == len(user):
            #We won't replace this in old_string, we'll replace the current entry
            #old_string = old_string.replace(a, '<' + user + '>')
            new_array[index] = '<%s>'%user

new_string = ' '.join(new_array)
```

Third way... this is a bit more complex, but what you really want is for any instance of `'@anything'` to be replaced with `<@anything>` (perhaps with whitespace?). You can do this in one shot with `re.sub`:

```
new_string = re.sub(r'(@\w+)', r'<\g<0>>', old_string)
```

Answer (score 2):

My previous answer was based entirely on correcting the problems in your current code. But, there is a better way to do this, which is using regular expressions.

```
import re

oldstring = re.sub(r'(@\w+)\b', r'<\1>', oldstring)
```

For more information, see the documentation on the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module.

Answer (score 1):

Because `@me` occurs first in your array, your code replaces the `@me` in `@mentee`.

Simplest way to fix that is to add a space after the username that you want to be replaced:

```
old_string = old_string.replace(a + ' ', '<' + user + '> ')
                # I added space here ^         and here ^
```

A new problem occurs, though. The last word is not wrapped, because there's no space after it. A very simple way to fix it would be:

```
oldstring = oldstring + ' '

for mention in ... # Your loop

oldstring = oldstring[:-1]
```

Comment: This somehow did it but the last word `@wonderland` is not wrapped and it removes all the spaces between wrapped words.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, as long as there isn't any punctuation (like commas) next to the usernames.

```
def wrapUsers(content):
    L = content.split()
    newL = []
    for word in L:
        if word.startswith('@'): word = '<'+word+'>'
        newL.append(word)
    return " ".join(newL)
```